# Error while connecting to Oracle database from oracle SQL Developer though I've the oracle client installed

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I've installed Oracle client in my machine, when I'm trying to connect to the oracle database server from Oracle SQL Developer am getting the following error:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

But am able to connect to the server using sql plus and TOAD as well from my machine. What is the issue if Toad connects to the server why cant my Oracle sql developer could not connect??

checked all the possible solutions like:
tns strings checking, telnet to the server and its port, 
changing the oracle home in the sqldeveloper->tools->preferences->database->advanced tab.

None solved my issue. Is this the firewall issue?
If it is so how am able to connect using TOAD/sql plus ??

UPDATE: I'm connecting to the Oracle database server using the VPN.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can connect from the same PC to the same database server using a different then it isn't a firewall issue. The only real possibility is that you've set up the connection settings incorrectly, or at least differently; maybe using IP addresses sometimes and a DNS name that won't resolve here. You mentioned "tns strings"; are you using a TNS alias for any of the connections? Not sure we can help without you showing how you connect from SQL\*Plus, and your SQL Developer connection settings.

Comment: How are you configuring the connection in SQL Developer? Are you using the same TNS alias, or are you using a basic connection (from the drop-down list)? This might be a rare case where a screenshot could be useful.

Comment: yes am using the same TNS alias which I get from the drop-down list. As I don't have any other TNS aliases, I get only one i the drop-down list

Comment: Ae you sure you're picking up the same `tnsnames.ora` file from SQL Developer? [You can check/set the directory it's found from](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11612449/266304). Not sure if that's what you meant when you mentioned setting the Oracle home. If you're sure that's right can you configure it as a basic connection using the hostname/port/service name from the TNS entry and see if that works?