# Oracle connect to database - Enter TNS_ADMIN entry or blank for Current Worksheet Database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I type this command and connect with the right username and password, then I get this message box with a text field - "Enter TNS_ADMIN entry or blank for Current Worksheet Database" . I enter nothing and get an error -

> Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected

How do I connect to a database so that I can run queries only on that database ?
Also, what is the meaning of that message box ? Google searches gave me nothing 
useful to fix the problem.

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425029/oracle-tns-names-not-showing-when-adding-new-connection-to-sql-developer

Comment: @Annjawn - I am not sure if its completely related to my problem.

Comment: You tagged SQL Developer so I assume that it is related to that. `TNS_ADMIN` is an environment variable that needs to be set properly and the URL says how to do it.