# connectString in oracledb node module

Tags: node.js, tnsnames, tns, node-oracledb

I am using oracledb in my Node server for connecting to a TNS Connection Alias. This is my code:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

    oracledb.getConnection(
        {
            user: "test",
            password: "test",
            connectString: "ADMISSIONS"
        },
        function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                logger.error("Error is: " + err.message);
                callback(null, err);
                return;
            } else {
                logger.loud("Connection successful!");
            }
});
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

> TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I am sure my `connectString` is wrong. Can anyone please help with what should be the value of `connectString` if I want to connect to a TNS Connection Alias called **Admissions** ? Please note this is NOT a localhost/XE connection.

Comment: Are you able to connect using this TNS connection alias using other applications, say `sqlplus` ? This error usually occurs when your entry in TNS entry is wrong/ not consistent with your network.

Comment: This is a TNS related error rather than a `'oracledb'` error

Comment: I am able to connect to "Admissions" alias successfully through SQL Developer upon defining "Connecting type" as TNS

Comment: `ADMISSIONS` or `Admissions` ? And in which file have you defined the alias.

Comment: "ADMISSIONS". The alias is defined by our organisation and I dont have access to the file (or system) where it is defined. It just appears in the drop down menu of TNS Connection type in SQL Developer

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the SQL developer picks it up from some place, where `'oracledb'` is not looking for...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425029/oracle-tns-names-not-showing-when-adding-new-connection-to-sql-developer

Comment: So all I need to do is to point oracledb connectString to the file called **tnsnames.ora** ?

Comment: Your connection string should be in `tnsnames.ora`

Comment: do a `find` for `tnsname.ora` on your file system. You might be able to spot it

Comment: I did a find for tnsname.ora, but couldn't find it anywhere in my system. Is it possible that SQL developer is picking it up from some network location? I assume that's what's happening that's why I can't see it in my local FS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019230/use-tnsnames-ora-in-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: You are a legend! I copied the latest tnsnames.ora file form another machine into my DEV machine and it works. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was outdated `tnsnames.ora` file. I copied the latest version of `tnsnames.ora` file into my `/etc` directory and the connection is successful. Thanks to @Malice